# How deal with TypeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, pandas, functools

I have a function called 'generate_wind_cap_new_data' which returns a pandas dataframe.

I want to cut this one by a specific timerange. My code is:

```
generate_wind_cap = partial(generate_wind_cap_new_data,freq='1T')['2011-1-1':'2011-12-31']
```

But I get the error:
TypeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

How can I handle the error? Or is there another possible way?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you using `partial`?

Comment: My function head looks 'def generate_wind_cap_new_data(freq='1T'):' Sometime I changed the frequency and therefore I used partial. Is there another way?

Comment: that error means that what `partial` returns cannot be sliced/indexed.

Comment: Okay. So what can I do? Should I easily exclude 'partial' from the code?

Comment: i'm not sure what `partial` does.  can you just do `generate_wind_cap_new_data(freq='1T')['2011-1-1':'2011-12-31']`?

Comment: Okay. I try generate_wind_cap_new_data(freq='1T')['2011-1-1':'2011-12-31'], but get for the returned series 'Series' object is not callable and if I only use generate_wind_cap_new_data['2011-1-1':'2011-12-31'] I also get TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__' .

Answer (score 0):

functools.partial returns a callable object, in other words, the returned value from partial is (in effect) a function.  So your code is like writing generate_wind_cap_new_data['2011-1-1':'2011-12-31'].  I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you probably need to *call* the function that is returned from partial.

Comment: So, okay. I have tried out something. No I use: `generate_wind_cap = generate_wind_cap_new_data['2011-1-1':'2011-12-31']` and get again: TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__' I mean, I can not be so difficult, but I don`t get it!!